# How to add a RemedyForce incident via the Rest API?

Tags: rest-api

I'm new to both Salesforce and RemedyForce. I have an account in our sandbox and I've navigated through the OAuth2 security and gotten my tokens to access the BMCServiceDesk_Incident__c class description and viewing the available objects of that type. What I'm looking for now is any guidance on creating such an object directly via the REST API. Is there any docs out there addressing the RemedyForce portion of the REST API or any personal experience with this part?

Answer (score 1):

Remedyforce dont have any exposed REST API I guess. But you can use the Salesforce REST API for creating the records of the Incident type. You will need to make a POST call on URL something like

`http://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c`
In body you will need to pass the fieldnames and its values in JSON format, something like below

```
{    
    "fieldname" : "Testrecord"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had actually gotten that far, but I'm not sure which of the fields for that class is required. In the absence of a more direct RemedyForce API, has anyone added an incident directly using any API (REST, SOAP or Apex)?

Comment: AFAIK Category, Template, or Request Definition are the required fields for the Incident object.